# Can link in Obj C, can't find symbols and won't link in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I'm working to convert an iOS project someone else wrote from Obj C to Swift.

The project in the Obj C form builds and runs fine, and shows that it's under x86_64 architecture.

When I try to build in Swift, I get the error 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64'. The message is :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewColumnHeader", referenced from:
      __TFC13CVTableLayout14ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ in ViewController.o
      __TFC13CVTableLayout14ViewController32collectionViewTableLayoutManagerfS0_FTGSQCSo34DRCollectionViewTableLayoutManager_14collectionViewGSQCSo16UICollectionView_19headerViewForColumnSu9indexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__GSQCSo24UICollectionReusableView_ in ViewController.o
```

The values referenced are defined in DRCollectionViewTableLayout.h, between #import  and the @class line, like this:

```
/**
*  Supplementary View kind for column headers


*/
static NSString * const DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewColumnHeader = @"DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewColumnHeader";

/**
 *  Supplementary View kind for row headers
 */
static NSString * const DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewRowHeader = @"DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewRowHeader";
```

My bridging header file is in place and looks like this:

```
#import "DRCollectionViewTableLayout.h"
#import "DRCollectionViewTableLayoutManager.h"
```

My viewDidLoad which references these constants is below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewColumnHeader, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderIdentifier)

    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewRowHeader, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderIdentifier)


    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier)

    let collectionViewLayout = DRCollectionViewTableLayout(delegate: self.collectionManager)
    collectionViewLayout.horizontalSpacing = 5.0
    collectionViewLayout.verticalSpacing = 5.0
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout
    collectionView.dataSource = collectionManager
    collectionView.delegate = collectionManager
}
```

My .m files and .swift are in the target.

I have deleted the DerivedData.

I'm using xcode 6.3.2

Any ideas why it won't link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I redeclare the constants in the swift file, the problem goes away. I think the problem is the "static" use in the Obj C file.  So I added this to my view controller. I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but after two days of trying I'll go with it:

```
let DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewColumnHeader = "DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewColumnHeader"
let DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewRowHeader = "DRCollectionViewTableLayoutSupplementaryViewRowHeader"
```